# How to find items from a list of strings based on another list of integers where values are used as index numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings like this:

```
lst = ["this", "that", "cat", "dog", "crocodile", "blah"]
```

And I have another list of integers like:

```
index_nr = [2,3]
```

My goal is to take the numbers from `index_nr` and get the list items from `lst` with the corresponding index number. If we stick to the example above, the desired output would be

```
['cat', 'dog']
```

Given that, 0: "this", 1: "that", 2: "cat", 3: "dog", 4: "crocodile", and 5: "blah".

I know that:

```
print(lst[2:4])
```

would throw the desired output, but I'm not sure how to use the values in `index_nr` to achive the same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
lst = ["this", "that", "cat", "dog", "crocodile", "blah"]
index_nr = [2, 3]

out = [lst[index] for index in index_nr]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['cat', 'dog']
```

---

Or standard `for`-loop:

```py
out = []
for index in index_nr:
    out.append(lst[index])
print(out)
```

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could index `lst` inside `index_nr` like this: `index_nr = [lst[2],lst[3]]`

Comment: It definitely could work! But for this solution, you need to handle every value of `index_nr` individually. So, you need to add "2" and "3" manually to `index_nr = [lst[2],lst[3]]`. I try to have a solution where you can generally use the value of `index_nr`.